# How to return an entity-based result using RawSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I have an older project where some of the code is in VB .NET.

Does anyone know the syntax for returning an entity-based result using VB .NET with RawSQL? I do this all the time in C#, but the syntax is different and I haven't been able to get it working.

This is the VB .NET code:

```
Dim Students As Entities.Students
Students = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(Of Entities.Students)("select ....").FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

```
Dim Students As Entities.Students
Students = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(Of Entities.Students)("select ....").FirstOrDefault()
```

The C# for the above would be something like (I didn't compile, so it may not be exactly the right syntax):

```
EntitiesStudents Students;
Students = dbContext.Students.SqlQuery("select ....").FirstOrDefault();
```